# Is there a way to set the Doom3 screen resolution when starting the game?

Tags: doom-3

I am running Doom3 on Linux. Everything worked out fine, as described in this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Doom3) but I ran into a fix when I changed my screen resolution.

Now the games starts in a bigger window, the bottom part of which is inaccessible as it extends beyond my laptop screen size. The mouse pointer moves only inside this window, so neither can use the Doom UI nor can I move this Doom window to make the UI visible.

Is there a config file somewhere where I can specify the screen resolution, or some command-line parameters with which to start Doom3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, exit the game.  Then open the `base/DoomConfig.cfg` file inside your Doom 3 installation directory and edit or add the following values, substituting your desired resolution and aspect ratio.

```
seta r_customHeight "1050"
seta r_customWidth "1680"
seta r_mode "-1"
seta r_aspectRatio "2"
```

The **aspect ratio** values are 0 for 4:3, 1 for 16:9 and 2 for 16:10.

You can also run these commands in-game if you have access to the developer's console (opened with the backtick/tilde key).  If you go that route, you also need to run `vid_restart` after changing these settings.

Comment: +1, this works for all games based on the Tech 3 engine. :)

Comment: the aspect ratio doesn't change for me... I can set the resolution just fine, but the mars planet in the main menu is still very, very oval :( (1600x900)

Comment: I take that back - it fixes in game, the menu just doesn't change. Thanks!